# Do we have any option similar to Azure CLI's --debug switch in Azure Powershell?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-cli, azure-management-api

The `--debug` switch in Azure CLI is very useful for me.

Do we have such feature (--debug) in Azure Poweshell?

Please note that I am not asking how to debug PowerShell scripts. I am looking for a feature to trace the calls that Azure Poweshell cmdlets are making to `management.azure.com` without using the tools like WireShark. Azure CLI's --debug perfectly does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run Azure PowerShell cmdlets in [`Debug`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7#debug) mode. This is known as a [common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7), which can be used with *any* cmdlet.

For example, you could run `Get-AzResourceGroup -Debug` to trace the GET request to `https://management.azure.com` and all the *programmer-level detail* operations happening in the background to fetch the resource groups from the ARM API.